# Как создать маршрут между точками используя плагин vue-yandex-maps во vue 3?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, vue3

Пытаюсь создать маршрут таким образом:

У меня имеется массив точек на карте, допустим: `[['55.7961', '37.7048'], ['55.8337', '37.7644'], ['55.8337', '37.7634']]`

Мне нужно построить маршрут между ними.
Плагин мне предоставляет доступ к глобальному инстансу `ymaps`, который я пытаюсь использовать так:

```
const points = [['55.7961', '37.7048'], ['55.8337', '37.7644'], ['55.8337', '37.7634']]
const multiRoute = new window.ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
            {
                referencePoints: points,
            },
            {
                boundsAutoApply: true
            }
        );

window.ymaps.geoObjects.add(multiRoute); // ???????????????
```

И вот на последней строчке у меня непонимание - в глобальном инстансе нет `geoObjects`, поэтому что делать дальше я не понимаю. Плюс у меня ощущение, что использование конструкции new `window.ymaps` тоже здесь неадекватно.

Как сделать все правильно используя `vue-yandex-maps`?

Comment: geoObjects - это свойство карты. Ты ведь карту уже создал? Вот к её геообъектам и добавляй маршрут.